# Angular ng-repeat input filter doubling first character in search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an input element on my page to filter my result set. When I start typing in the text box, it always doubles the first character typed.

Here's the html:

```
<input ng-model="query" type=search results=5 name=s placeholder="{{translation._SEARCH_}}..." style="text-align: left" />
<div ng-repeat="eu in EligibleUsers | orderBy: Username | filter: query">
    <a style="border: 1px solid green; border-radius: 5px; background-color: light-gray; width: 100%; margin: 5px; height: 100px;" ng-click="Impersonate(eu.Username)">
        <span>{{eu.Username}}</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's the controller variable:

```
$scope.query = "";
```

Here's the EligibleUsers:

```
var successGetImpersonateUsers = function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var impersonateUser = data[i];

                $scope.EligibleUsers.push(impersonateUser);
            }
        }
    };
```

So, if I type in "a" in the search box, it displays "aa". If I try and quickly type "ab", it displays "aab".

Edit: I deleted the $scope.query from my controller and I'm still getting the same behavior.

Edit: It only duplicates the first character when it's bound to my scope "query" variable. Once I remove that ng-model="query", then the duplication doesn't occur anymore...

Edit: When entering a single character, ie "a", and letting it double-up, so "aa", then hitting the delete key once, it actually removes both of the a's.

NOTE: please ignore my lackof/horrible styling...

Comment: Where is the EligibleUsers? Could you show how it is?

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mejzXDuUb7cHOFvjkZxw?p=preview Are you using `query` somewhere else in your view/controller which could be colliding with this usage? BTW, you need to wrap your `orderBy` expression in quotes as you'll see demonstrated in the Plunker.

Comment: @rafaels88 I updated the code to show eligible users...

Comment: The [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mejzXDuUb7cHOFvjkZxw?p=preview) I posted based on your sample code does not replicate the behavior you're describing. Can you fork it and modify it in such a way that it does?

Comment: @MarcKline I removed the $scope.query = ""; from my controller completely and I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: @MarcKline well, I'm not able to reproduce it in plunker...thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Wish I could help more. I suggest that you can continue to compare your code vs the Plunker in an attempt to isolate the problem.

Comment: I've identified that it's ONLY on the iOS Simulator on the Mac. Works just fine on a mobile device.

Comment: Make sure you put quotes around your HTML attribute values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified that it's ONLY on the iOS simulator on the Mac that this occurs. Obviously [I think] a bug in the simulator, and nothing wrong with Angular. Google wins again!